# onclick functions are running automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, onclick

I'm using a combination of JavaScript, HTML and PHP for a project I'm working on. Basically, I'm creating several onclick links and for each of these links I want a specific JavaScript function to run. The JavaScript functions each have some PHP code that defines two variables, a longitude and latitude coordinate. However, the JavaScript functions always run automatically and the longitude and latitude coordinate end up being what was defined in the last function, AR7().

This is the JavaScript code I have defining the functions:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
function AR6() {
    <?php $lat = 77; $long = -170;?>
}
function AR7() {
    <?php $lat = 77; $long = -140;?>
}
</script>
```

And the HTML code I have for implementing the functions:

```
<a onclick="AR6()">AR6</a>
<a onclick="AR7()">AR7</a>
```

I'm fairly new to using JavaScript so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your functions don't do anything. Once that page is rendered your functions are completely empty. If you need to execute PHP you'll need to make an ajax call back to the server, or replace your logic with Javascript.

Comment: php is a server side language and javascript is a client side language. Defining $a = 1; and then defining $a = 2; will always mean that $a will be 2, regardless the javascript code, because the PHP code has already been executed. Perhaps you're looking for AJAX requests?

Comment: ad two hiden input which id is lat and long.
set this value on your JS function :

Answer (score 0):

add two hiden input which id is lat and lon in your HTML.

```
<input type="Text" id="lon" value="" visibility="hidden"/>
<input type="Text" id="lat" value="" visibility="hidden"/>
```

set this value on your JavaScript function :

```
function AR6() {
   Document.GetElementByID('lat').Value="77";
   Document.GetElementByID('lon').Value="-170";
}
```

AR7 function will be same with different values.